# How to synchronize a local folder with a remote?

Tags: remote, shared-folders, rsync

I want to upload a batch of files to my server periodically preserving the originals only in the server, that is:

- If I delete the local folder, files are not ereased from the server.
- If local files are replaced, they are added to remote.
- It should restore the transfer if the connection is lost during the process.
- Bonus points if it works in Windows

I thought that rsync and a cron job should do the trick but I happen to have no idea about how to use those (well, ok... I have ONE idea about how to use cron).

Comment: I find grsync a bit easier to use. It is a GUI front-end to rsync. Once you figure out which options are needed / not needed. You can create a command line equivalent and pass it through cron.

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/a/31530/63898

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend Unison, which can sync between unix and windows.  It's built on top of the same technology as rsync, but it is a lot easier to set up:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/unison2.27.57-gtk/

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

It supports exclude/include lists, remote or local syncs, no-delete mode, and lots of other common options.  It can recover from a partial sync due to bad connection or anything else quite easily.

You can run it interactively or as a batch process using cron.